# Which object is the source of this binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I see DataGrid databinding sytax as below:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListDataColumns, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

The more complete code is:

```
    <DataGrid KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"  DataContext="{Binding}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListDataColumns, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="DataGridColumnConfig" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"  GridLinesVisibility="All" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedItemIndex}">
```

I think the code is binding to a property called "ListDataColumns".

How can I determine from the ItemSource that which object is being bound to?

Comment: The `ItemSource` is the property `ListDataColumns` of the `DataContext` that is bound to the `DataGrid`. It is not bound to an UIElement cause this would need to include the `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` in the Binding definition.

Comment: Not sure I understand what's the question here.. you want to get to the binded object in run-time or just understand the concept of bindings?

Comment: I want to get to know how to know where the data come from.

Comment: It comes from ListDataColumns property, which has to be a public property of the usercontrol's datacontext. If you don't know how to find it, simply search for the string in every .cs file.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question completely, we would need more information from you. However, with what you have provided (and using a simplified XAML example), we can tell you the following:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListDataColumns, 
    Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedItemIndex}" ... />
```

1. The `DataContext` is set to `{Binding}` which is the same as `{Binding Path=.}` and means that we are binding to the current `Binding.Source`... in other words, one of the parents of this control *should* have an instance of an object set as its `DataContext` and this control will *share* that same object and have access to the same properties.
2. The `ItemsSource` property is set to `{Binding Path=ListDataColumns ...}` which is the same as `{Binding ListDataColumns ...}` and means that it will look in whatever object is set as the `DataContext` (of the parent control) for a property named `ListDataColumns`.
3. The `SelectedItem` property is set to `{Binding Path=SelectedItem}` which is the same as `{Binding SelectedItem}` and means that it will look in whatever object is set as the `DataContext` (of the parent control) for a property named `SelectedItem`.
4. The `SelectedIndex` property is set to `{Binding Path=SelectedItemIndex}` which is the same as `{Binding SelectedItemIndex}` and means that it will look in whatever object is set as the `DataContext` (of the parent control) for a property named `SelectedItem`.

That is about all that can be taken from your XAML example (ignoring the other `Binding` properties). However, for users learning XAML and WPF, here are some very useful links on MSDN for help with property path syntax:

[Binding.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx)

[PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx)

[Property Path Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)